# Can I plot HTML5 Canvas x/y points programatically using jQuery with external JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, canvas

I've got an HTML5 canvas 'join the dots' type thing going - 2 lines with dots at their angle points - this is fine but I want to plot the X coordinates programatically with external JSON data (pulled from a 'local' server so won't need to be JSONP) - I hope I explain this clearly ...

I'm not trying to convert the JSON data into new DOM elements, but instead I need to apply the data to the actual *script* which maps the canvas coordinates. Ideally I want to use jQuery for this and my guess is that I will need to parse a JSON object via .getJSON(), but this is where I need some help.

Both X and Y coordinates are currently initiated with hard-coded variables in the canvas script but I want the JSON data to parse into the X variable programatically (the Y co-ords can stay hard coded and work fine for both lines).

Here's a fiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/ByT58/6/

Here's the markup/script for reference - and big thanks in advance for any help!:

HTML:

```
<div class="canvas-wrap">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="115"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Here's how the external JSON would look:

```
{
    "red": {
        "r01x": 20,
        "r02x": 149,
        "r03x": 50
    },
    "blue": {
        "b01x": 80,
        "b02x": 179,
        "b03x": 20
    }
}
```

JS:

```
var ctx = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');

// set attributes for all circles
var radius = 7;

// set attributes for all lines
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';

// set X co-ords for Red
var r01x = 20;
var r02x = 149;
var r03x = 50;

// set X co-ords for Blue
var b01x = 80;
var b02x = 179;
var b03x = 20;

// Set default Y coordinates for both Red and Blue
var y01 = 20;
var y02 = 50;
var y03 = 100;

// RED dots
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#E51919";
ctx.arc(r01x, y01, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#E51919";
ctx.arc(r02x, y02, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#E51919";
ctx.arc(r03x, y03, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

// RED line
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(r01x, y01);
ctx.lineTo(r02x, y02);
ctx.lineTo(r03x, y03);     
ctx.strokeStyle = "#E51919";
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

// BLUE dots
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#133175";
ctx.arc(b01x, y01, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#133175";
ctx.arc(b02x, y02, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#133175";
ctx.arc(b03x, y03, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

// BLUE line
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(b01x, y01);
ctx.lineTo(b02x, y02);
ctx.lineTo(b03x, y03);     
ctx.strokeStyle = "#133175";
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
```

Comment: Do you notice that you repeat the code? Doesn't that hint you that you should use an array and a loop?

Comment: Yes, and the logic would be 1: plot the json key/value into a multidimensional array, 2: use `.each()` to parse the array and insert the array key/value into the canvas script variables.
Trouble is that my chops aren't up to that - I could possibly do this for elements inserted into the DOM but don't know how to parse them into the canvas script. I'm guessing so came here for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to put your JSON data into the form:

```
{
    red:  { color: "#E51919", x: [20,149,50] },
    blue: { color: "#133175", x: [80,179,20] }
}
```

Your draw function would look something like ([jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ByT58/8/)):

```
function draw(data) {
    var ctx = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');

    // set attributes for all circles
    var radius = 7;

    // set attributes for all lines
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';

    var y = [20,50,100];
    for(var key in data) {
        var x = data[key].x;
        ctx.fillStyle = data[key].color;
        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x[i], y[i], radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x[0], y[0]);
        ctx.lineTo(x[1], y[1]);
        ctx.lineTo(x[2], y[2]);
        ctx.strokeStyle = data[key].color;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}

draw({
    red:  { color: "#E51919", x: [20,149,50] },
    blue: { color: "#133175", x: [80,179,20] }
});
```

Using JQuery to retrieve the JSON data from the server use [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) or [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/?s=.ajax)

for example (no error handling...):

```
$.getJSON('path/data.json', function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(textStatus);
    draw(data);
})
.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown ); });
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks very much!
Works perfectly on my localhost with the json data included in the script file. However, when I comment out the inline json and use `$getJSON` it doesn't work, and I'm not getting any console error. I've updated the fiddle to reflect what I'm doing locally, is there anything obviously wrong there? [jsfiddle.net/ByT58/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/ByT58/11/)

Comment: I am calling jquery cdn in the localhost file so that's not the problem.

Comment: Can advise here please? I'm not trying to be lazy but I can't see where this is going wrong. 
In the console I'm getting `http://localhost:9000/html5/canvas/data-3.json` and a 200 OK message, I've got console logs before and after the json call so I believe everything is loading fine. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Hard to say - You might try accessing data-3.json directly in the browser.  The only thing I can suggest is to set a breakpoint in your handler and walk through the code to get a better idea of what might be happening. BTW: also updated the sample above with an error handler to show you how to get more detail on a failure.

Comment: Thanks, actually tried both of what you mentioned, can see the file fine in browser and syntax error with 2x .fail functions, bummer. Also happens that jsonlint is calling a syntax error on the json data, the same data that works fine when referenced inline. I'm gonna hit a few books but also check out from this for now - uk hours. Thanks so far I'll hit this again later.