# Canvas : How to Plot circles from external JSON file on canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Json should content : color, x-cordinate, y-cordinate

My Code: Giving Error
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of null
draw 
(anonymous function)
"
Code:

```
<head>
<style>
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 40px 0 0;
        background: #efefef;
    }
    .canvas-wrap {
        background: #fff;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
<script src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>

<script>
function draw(data) {
    //var ctx = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // set attributes for all circles
    var radius = 7;

    // set attributes for all lines
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';

    for(var key in data) {
        var x = data[key].x;
        var y = data[key].y;
        ctx.fillStyle = data[key].color;
        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x[i], y[i], radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

    }
}
```

//problem is draw() how can I pass JSON here?

```
draw({
    red:  { color: "#E51919", x: [20,50], y:[20, 50] },
    blue: { color: "#133175", x: [100], y:[50] },
    green: { color: "green", x: [10], y:[50] }
});
</script>

</body oonload="draw(this)>
<div class="canvas-wrap">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="115"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
```

Ref :http://jsfiddle.net/ByT58/6/
http://jsfiddle.net/ByT58/8/
[Can I plot HTML5 Canvas x/y points programatically using jQuery with external JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001360/can-i-plot-html5-canvas-x-y-points-programatically-using-jquery-with-external-js)

Comment: What external JSON file? Currently you just are [calling `draw(…)` too early](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1048572)

Comment: Json data= [  
  {
   "color": "#E51919",
   "x": ["10", "20"],
   "y": ["10", "20"]   
  }, 
  {
   "color": "#133175",
   "x": ["40", "20"]
   "y": ["30", "40"]  
  }
  
  
 ];       I want to pass these

Comment: That seems to be neither JSON nor external. Where is that file located?

Comment: In the reference example they are passing data with data({}) .... but i want to pass json object containing "color, x cordinate, y cordinate". Any reference for the same with pure javascript?

Comment: I will be posting my answer soon.

Comment: You’ve presented too little info for a good answer, but in general: “Cannot call method getContext of null” would normally be if your canvas variable is not referencing a valid canvas element.  And your question “how can I pass JSON here” would be answered by this link:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/